# Use an actionbutton to go to another tab

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab 1",
      actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the second tab")
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
    tabPanel("Tab 3", "there!"))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$switch_tab, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                      selected = "Tab 3")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It should basically switch tabs when I click the button "Go to the second tab". Its not working however.

Any feedback on what I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `id` to tabsetpanel

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
        tabsetPanel(
                id="inTabset",
                tabPanel("Tab 1",actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the third tab")
                ),
                tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
                tabPanel("Tab 3", "there!"))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

        observeEvent(input$switch_tab, {
                updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",selected = "Tab 3")
        })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```